# $ \frac{R[x]}{(x^m)} \otimes_R \frac{R[y]}{(y^n)} \cong \frac{R[x,y]}{(x^m,y^n)} $ as $R$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, tensor-products

For a commutative ring $R$ with $1$, do we have 
$$ R[x]/(x^m) \otimes_R R[y]/(y^n) \cong R[x,y]/(x^m,y^n) $$
as $R$-algebras?
I know that $R[x] \otimes _R R[y] \cong R[x,y]$ as $R$-algebras. Can we deduce the above isomorphism using this?

Comment: Yes we do: identify the kernel of the map $R[x,y]\to R[x]\otimes R[y]\to R[x]/(x^m)\otimes R[y]/(y^n)$.

Comment: We have a map $R[X,Y]/(X^m, Y^n)\to R[x]/(x^m)\otimes _R R[y]/(y^n)$ which is given on generators by $X\to x\otimes 1$ and $Y\to 1\otimes y$. (The relations $X^m$ and $Y^n$ are sent to zero.) Can we also write an inverse map explicitly?!

Comment: Why are you affraid with the inverse map ? And I'd say (for $R\subset S$ unital commutative) $S\otimes_R R[y]/(y^m) = S[y]/(y^m)$ is quite the definition of tensor products.